# Failed to import 3rd party material sass/scss files in Angular 6 Project

Tags: angular, material-design, angular6

Can I use Material components in Angular? If so, what is the correct way to do it?

I am using the guide of this **[link](https://material.io/develop/web/components/image-lists/)**

I used: `npm install @ material/image-list`

Then I import in my style.scss: `@import "@material/image-list/mdc-image-list";`

And when compiling I get the following error:

> ERROR in ./src/styles.scss
>   (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
>   Module build failed: @import "@material/image-list/mdc-image-list"; ^
>   File to import not found or unreadable:
>   @material/image-list/mdc-image-list. in
>   /Users/pacozevallos/cuscoAvisos/avisos/src/styles.scss (line 66,
>   column 1)

Then when I check `mdc-image-list.scss` I find this:
[image]

Comment: I am also using Angular Material, but that is not my query, thank you.

Comment: My query is if you can use the Material Design components, if so? What is the right way. If you check in the specific link clearly, it is Material Design and not Angular Material. By the way Angular material I already have it installed.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear. What happens is that there are some components that are more complete in Material Design for example I tried to use Grid-list of Angular Material but I want a masonry grid and that I can get with Material Design (image-list). Just to give an example.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll step out, since I don't have a good answer, but you should put that in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to configure Angular CLI to fix this issue.

By default, it searches for `./`.

`@import "@material/image-list/mdc-image-list"` === import from `./@material/image-list/mdc-image-list`

But this is a third party module that stored in `node_modules`.

Open `angular.json` file and change `stylePreprocessorOptions.includePaths` propery.

```
stylePreprocessorOptions": {
   "includePaths": [
       ".",
       "./node_modules" 
   ]
}
```

---

Sample Config:

```
{
 // ...
 "styles": [ ],
  "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
     "includePaths": [
         ".",
         "./node_modules" 
      ]
   },
  "scripts": []
  // ...
}
```

---

There is an alternative solution. You can use `~` sign to tell Angular CLI that pick this from `node_module`.

E.g. `@import "~@material/image-list/mdc-image-list"`

But it'll not work for this setup as this `scss` has also dependency that need to be searched from `node_module`.

---

Reference: [Angular Wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles)

Comment: It's what I needed, it worked very well. Thanks for the correction and the response.